# Bash: Succinct way to loop over lines from stdin or command line arguments?

Tags: bash

I've got a bash script I'd like to loop over the lines in stdin, or loop over each argument passed in.

Is there a clean way to write this so I don't have to have 2 loops?

```
#!/bin/bash

# if we have command line args... 
if [ -t 0 ]
then
  # loop over arguments
  for arg in "$@" 
  do
    # process each argument
  done
else
  # loop over lines from stdin
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    # process each line
  done
fi
```

EDIT: I'm looking for a generic solution that just uses a single loop, as I find I want to do this quite often, but have always wrote out 2 loops and then called a function instead. So maybe something that turns stdin into an array, so I could use a single loop instead?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish ? Sounds like a [typical XY question...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676)

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? What kind of processing needs to happen in the loop?

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I write lots of little bash scripts that I like to be able to accepts args from the command line, or from stdin. The particular script i'm writing now is one that will concatenate arguments using a delimiter, so I can write both `cat /tmp/it | concat` and `concat a b c` and it'd join these arguments together in both cases, trimming each arg and putting a comma between items. e.g. `a,b,c`.

Comment: Just a note that instead of `cat` use of `< /tmp/it` is encouraged. e.g. `< /tmp/it | while ...` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can also use redirection of standard input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
test -t 0 && exec < <(printf '%s\n' "$@")
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

test with :

```
test.sh Hello World
test.sh < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: as requested - succinct!

Answer (score 14):

Create data for your `while read` loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    # We have command line arguments.
    # Output them with newlines in-between.
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
else
    # No command line arguments.
    # Just pass stdin on.
    cat
fi |
while IFS= read -r string; do
    printf 'Got "%s"\n' "$string"
done
```

Note that your `concat` example can be done with the `while read` loop replaced by `tr '\n' ','` or similar.

Also, the `-t` test says nothing about whether you have command line arguments or not.

---

Alternatively, to process *both* command line arguments and standard input (in that order):

```
#!/bin/sh

{
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        # We have command line arguments.
        # Output them with newlines in-between.
        printf '%s\n' "$@"
    fi

    if [ ! -t 0 ]; then
        # Pass stdin on.
        cat
    fi
} |
while IFS= read -r string; do
    printf 'Got "%s"\n' "$string"
done
```

Or, using short-cut notation that some people seems to like:

```
#!/bin/sh

{
    [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && printf '%s\n' "$@"
    [ ! -t 0 ]     && cat
} |
while IFS= read -r string; do
    printf 'Got "%s"\n' "$string"
done
```

Comment: Note that that changes the behaviour if there are arguments that contain newline characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, command line arguments with literal newlines in them will be broken up into multiple items when they arrive at the loop.

Answer (score 2):

With `bash` specifically, you could do:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
  args=("$@")
else
  readarray -t args
fi
for i in "${args[@]}"; do
   ...
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get access to STDIN descriptor, so:

```
for i in $(cat /dev/stdin) ; do echo $i ; done
```